# onPress event not called on react-native element

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am using react-native-elements to add an Avatar and want to perform an action when the Avatar is pressed.

```
import { Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';

        <Avatar
            size={50}
            rounded
            title="Mb"
            containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#3d4db7' }}
            onPress={() => addEvent}
          />

  const addEvent = async () => {
    console.log("add Event pressed")
    navigation && navigation.navigate("addEvent")
  }
```

I also tried `onPress={() => addEvent()}` and `onPress={addEvent}`, nothing worked

Comment: Is there another element or container that is capturing press events?

Comment: I just noticed that the pressing is working, but only in one small area of the avatar. I have to click in the center on the top of the avatar. Is there a way to make the pressing area bigger?

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap the avatar within a Pressable Component

```js
import { Pressable } from 'react-native'

<Pressable onPress={addEvent}> 
  <Avatar
    size={50}
    rounded
    title="Mb"
    containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#3d4db7' }}
  />
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 1):

because Avatar doesn't provide onPress prop.
onPress prop is only available for Button, touchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, TouchableNativeFeedback, and TouchableHighlight